# Somar os dados de uma tabela html

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria que apresenta-se o valor total e não NAN...

```js
function sumQuantity() {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('itemTable');
  var sum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML);
  };

  alert(sum);


}

sumQuantity();
```

```html
<table class="itemTable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="OrdersDataGrid" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-right:10px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8;">
      <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Id">Pedido</td>
      <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Date">Criado</td>
      <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Items">Itens</td>
      <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Proof">Prova</td>
      <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Price">Preço total</td>
      <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Status">Status</td>
      <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Options">Opções</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="48 G-CDC2B78C">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDC2B78C</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">23/03/2018 12:00</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl03_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl03$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="46 G-CDB4B78C">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB4B78C</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">23/03/2018 11:56</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl04_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl04$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="33 G-CDB7B78D">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB7B78D</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">21/03/2018 17:29</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl05_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl05$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="27 G-CDB3B78E">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB3B78E</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">21/03/2018 15:28</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 011 – Cupom Bio Running 50% de desconto</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 78,00</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl06_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl06$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="22 G-CDB8B78E">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB8B78E</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">21/03/2018 12:07</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 012 – Flyer BioNurtri Divulgação</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 33,00</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl07_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl07$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="16 G-CDB4B78F">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB4B78F</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 17:52</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 003 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO SMARTFIT FITNESSCHANNEL</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl08_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl08$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="13 G-CDB7B78F">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB7B78F</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 17:23</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 002 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO SMARTFIT</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl09_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl09$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="9 G-CDCAB797">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDCAB797</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 17:00</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl10_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl10$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="6 G-CDCAB78A">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDCAB78A</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 16:49</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl11_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl11$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="4 G-CDCAB78C">
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDCAB78C</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 16:48</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items">
        <p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof">
        <p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p>
      </td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price">R$ 35,50</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td>
      <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
        <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl12_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl12$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Essa tabela é dinâmica ou estática?

Comment: Olá Leandro a tabela é dinâmica

Comment: Os dados que preenchem a tabela vem como, Ajax?

Comment: Isso é um aspx uma aplicação chamada storefront da pageflex, sinceramente não sei como vem o preenchimento ... existe alguma forma de eu saber ?

Comment: Cara dá pra vc saber pelo console, enfim, voltando a pergunta, uma maneira de vc conseguir pegar o valor total dos preços seria vc colocar um id em cada linha onde vai o preço e pegar o valor e somar tudo.

Comment: ok, é que eu não consigo alterar esse código pois ele é fechado..
consigo apenas adicionar partes de código nessa pagina

Comment: Quando mudou o nome da classe para "td.itemTable-Price"

ele retorna 0  

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('td.itemTable-Price');

Comment: Inclusive se alguém tiver uma solução melhor que essa ...>>> agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ve se a alteracao que eu fiz te ajuda.

basicamente passei a usar a classe da `TD` que contem os valores `itemTable-Price` e fiz um replace no texto para transformar em `float`

```
function sumQuantity() 
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('itemTable-Price');
    var sum = 0;

    for (i=0;i< elements.length;i++) 
    {
        sum += parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/,/,'.').replace('R$',''));
    };

    alert(sum);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hmpwvgux/37/

Comment: Obrigado Icaro alem de ajudar deu uma aula >>>

Answer (score 0):

Cara estou meio sem tempo no trampo aí fiz meio que rapidão, é uma forma de se fazer, existem outras, até mais elegante, utilizei jQuery, ve se este código lhe atende

```js
  
  //var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('itemTable');
  var sum = 0;

  /* for (i=0;i< elements.length;i++) {
      sum = sum + parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML);
     }; */
     
     var preco1 = parseFloat($('#preco1').text());
     var preco2 = parseFloat($('#preco2').text());
     var preco3 = parseFloat($('#preco3').text());
     var preco4 = parseFloat($('#preco4').text());
     var preco5 = parseFloat($('#preco5').text());
     var preco6 = parseFloat($('#preco6').text());
     var preco7 = parseFloat($('#preco7').text());
     var preco8 = parseFloat($('#preco8').text());
     var preco9 = parseFloat($('#preco9').text());
     var preco10 = parseFloat($('#preco10').text());
     
     sum = preco1 + preco2 + preco3 + preco4 + preco5 +
     preco6 + preco7 + preco8 + preco9 + preco10;
          
    
   alert(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="itemTable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="OrdersDataGrid" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-right:10px;">
 <tbody><tr style="background-color:#E8E8E8;">
  <td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Id">Pedido</td><td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Date">Criado</td><td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Items">Itens</td><td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Proof">Prova</td><td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Price">Preço total</td><td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Status">Status</td><td class="itemTableHeader itemTableHeader-Options">Opções</td>
 </tr><tr class="48 G-CDC2B78C">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDC2B78C</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">23/03/2018 12:00</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco1"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl03_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl03$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="46 G-CDB4B78C">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB4B78C</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">23/03/2018 11:56</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco2"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl04_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl04$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="33 G-CDB7B78D">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB7B78D</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">21/03/2018 17:29</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco3"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl05_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl05$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="27 G-CDB3B78E">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB3B78E</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">21/03/2018 15:28</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 011 – Cupom Bio Running 50% de desconto</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco4"> 78,00</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl06_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl06$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="22 G-CDB8B78E">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB8B78E</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">21/03/2018 12:07</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 012 – Flyer BioNurtri Divulgação</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco5"> 33.00</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl07_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl07$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="16 G-CDB4B78F">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB4B78F</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 17:52</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 003 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO SMARTFIT FITNESSCHANNEL</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco6"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl08_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl08$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="13 G-CDB7B78F">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDB7B78F</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 17:23</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 002 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO SMARTFIT</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco7"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl09_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl09$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="9 G-CDCAB797">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDCAB797</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 17:00</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco8"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl10_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl10$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="6 G-CDCAB78A">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDCAB78A</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 16:49</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco9"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl11_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl11$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr><tr class="4 G-CDCAB78C">
  <td class="itemTable       itemTable-Id">G‑CDCAB78C</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Date">20/03/2018 16:48</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Items"><p class="itemTableLabelWithIcon"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> 001 – CARTÃO DE VISITA BIORITMO</p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Proof"><p class="proofLinks"><img align="absmiddle" width="18px" height="18px" src="Images/space.gif"> </p></td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Price" id="preco10"> 35.50</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Status"><img align="absmiddle" src="Images/OrderInProcessStatusIcon.png">&nbsp;Em processo</td><td class="itemTable       itemTable-Options">
                     <a id="OrdersDataGrid_ctl12_Linkbutton3" class="siteLink" name="Linkbutton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('OrdersDataGrid$ctl12$Linkbutton3','')">Detalhes</a>
                 </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Repare que eu tirei o R$ e troquei a , por . no html, mas, da para fazer isto com expressão regular.

Comment: Obrigado Leandro pelo empenho >>>>
Mas como disse nao consigo alterar os valores Mas o Icaro abaixo solucionou a charada....

Muito Obrigado

Comment: Opa, se resolveu aí pra vc, é o que vale man! Sucesso.